# Не учитывать клик, при выделении

Tags: javascript

Обработчик висит на элементе `main`. При клике по элементам внутри `main`, если элемент (цель клика) является потомком блока `message`, к соответствующему блоку `message` добавляется/удаляется класс `checked`.

Таким образом можно помечать сообщения, например для удаления.

Но вот **в чем проблема**: если я выделяю текст сообщения, то это считается за клик и сообщение выделяется. Я хочу чтобы при выделении текста в блоке `message` или его потомках (например `body`) блок `message` не обособлялся классом `checked`.

То есть если я кликаю по любому содержимому блока `message`, то блок `message` выделяется (классом), а если я выделяю текст в блоке `message`, то ничего происходить не должно.

```js
function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
    var elm = e.path[i];
    if (hasClass(elm, 'message')) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    return;
  }

  if (hasClass(elm, 'checked')) {
    elm.classList.remove('checked');
  } else {
    elm.classList.add('checked');
  }

});
```

```css
.message {
  background: yellow;
}

.checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="message">
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum, qwerty! Если текст выделен - цвет не должен переключиться</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7dousvo)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения можно сделать проверку, что если выделен какой-то текст, то выйти из обработчика.

Определить это можно с помощью свойства [isCollapsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/isCollapsed) объекта [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), который возвращает функция [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

Например:

```js
function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!getSelection().isCollapsed) return;
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
    var elm = e.path[i];
    if (hasClass(elm, 'message')) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    return;
  }

  if (hasClass(elm, 'checked')) {
    elm.classList.remove('checked');
  } else {
    elm.classList.add('checked');
  }

});
```

```css
.message {
  background: yellow;
}

.checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="message">
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum, qwerty! Если текст выделен - <span>клик</span> отменен</div>
  </div>
</div>
```